# storing 10 students information in a struct ,debug assertion failed error

Tags: c, struct

I wrote this but it keeps giving a debug assertion failed error after entering age.

I tried everything I knew and checked with online examples too but couldn't figure out what's wrong.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct student
{
    char name[50];
    float age;
    float grade[2];
    float gpa;

};

int main() {
    struct student s[10];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("please enter the %d student's name\n", i + 1);
        scanf_s(" %s ", &s[i].name, 20);
        printf("please enter the student's age\n");
        scanf_s("%f", &s[i].age);
        printf("please enter the physics score\n");
        scanf_s("%.2f", &s[i].grade[0]);
        printf("please enter the maths score\n");
        scanf_s("%.2f", &s[i].grade[1]);
        s[i].gpa = (s[i].grade[0] + s[i].grade[1]) / 2;
    }
    printf(" name\t\t age\t physics\tmaths\tgpa\n");
    printf("_____________________________________________________________________");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s\t %f\t %.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\n", s[i].name, s[i].age, s[i].grade[0], s[i].grade[1], s[i].gpa);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When does your crash happen? At first iteration of the loop, second or other? What is your input? Generally you should always check return values of `scanf` and similar. There is no need to use `scanf_s` when you don't input strings. And for strings you could also just use `scanf` with format specifier `%49s` to read into your `char[50]`. Also as `name` is an array, you should remove the `&` in `scanf`.

Comment: That is also a good time to start using a debugger. Step through your code and see where your crash happens and what values the involved variables hold at that time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using Microsoft Visual Studio. You need to tell us such details.

You're misusing `scanf_s` and the compiler warned you about this. These warnings should be considered as errors.

Forget `scanf_s` and use `scanf` instead. To be able to do so, you need to put this at the very top of your source code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Furthermore replace `"%.2f"` with `"%f"` and remember that `scanf` is not `printf`, some of the format specifiers as `%s` and `%d` are the same, whereas others are not. Also replace `scanf(" %s ", &s[i].name);` with `scanf("%s", s[i].name);`

Be aware that you cannot enter a name containing spaces with `scanf` and `%s`, use `"%[^\n]"` instead of `%s` (but that's an advanced topic), don't bother for the moment.

Anyway `scanf` is absolutely not suited for interative user input in real world programs, for small test programs it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct student
{
    char name[50];
    float age;
    float grade[2];
    float gpa;

};

int main() {
    struct student s[10];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("please enter the %d student's name\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", &s[i].name[0]);
        printf("please enter the student's age\n");
        scanf("%f", &s[i].age);
        printf("please enter the physics score\n");
        scanf("%f", &s[i].grade[0]);
        printf("please enter the maths score\n");
        scanf("%f", &s[i].grade[1]);
        s[i].gpa = (s[i].grade[0] + s[i].grade[1]) / 2;
    }
    printf(" name\t\t age\t physics\tmaths\tgpa\n");
    printf("_____________________________________________________________________");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s\t %f\t %.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\n", s[i].name, s[i].age, s[i].grade[0], s[i].grade[1], s[i].gpa);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code i just shared here is working how i believe you want it to.
Changes i made:
Used scanf instead of scanf_s;
Retired the spaces between the quotation marks on the first scanf();
Added [0] after &s[i].name in order to provide the scanf() function with a single address;
Also replaced %.2f with %f, the function scanf() doesn't allow it;